# After Domain Rename - gpfixup warning - Error 80070057

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rename

We run a simple AD (1 DC Server 2012)

We had to rename our domain name from a single label domain to: lan.domain.com

Following the step by step, all went well, until the last step (that worked perfectly in the dev env)

```
gpfixup /olddns:adatum.com /newdns:cpx.local
```

- [Step 23 in this guide](https://mizitechinfo.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/simple-guide-how-to-rename-domain-name-in-windows-server-2012/)

I assume the fixup didn't complete. Does that mean that the domain will/did not propogate to other clients?

- Do I need to wait for a gpupdate?
- What is this error about?

I want to mention, I did **NOT** change the netbios name for the new domain. If that has any effect.

The error I see is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the functions that `gpfixup` performs is to rewrite any Software Installation Policy paths that refer to domain DFS locations (as those locations will change when a domain rename occurs).

It looks like something went awry when it attempted to "fix" the path in the Group Policy Object (GPO) where you install the "TeamViewer Host (MSI Wrapper)" package. I haven't seen this behavior before.

I'd go examine that GPO to see if the installation path is still correct. If it isn't, I'd delete the package from the GPO and add it again, specifying the correct path.

Comment: From where to fix path? GPO is not loading. Is there anyway? I am newbie. I am facing exactly the same problem which Saariko asked.

Answer (score 4):

I found the reason for the problem I also got:

The attribute "packageFlags" in ldap (from eg: CN=28fc4a18-4476-48ce-81af-a35890ca8c0e,CN=Packages,CN=Class Store,CN=Machine,CN={FCDD4C11-FBCC-45B4-9655-7A327138A512},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=domain,DC=local) holds as example -1610593168.

When I delete the value in adsiedit, it works. So there are two options: the value is invalid or there is a problem with server 2012 r2 gpofixup tool (or relevant dlls).

When it is invalid, there is again one question: why?
I come from a Server 2003 domain, which I updated to a server 2012r2.

at least deleting the packageFlags, also delete the package from the gpo, but the gpofixup tool dont crash.

Comment: I have same problem, can you plz guide?

Comment: Kudos for this! Had an exact issues and this solved it. Wouldn't find it myself in a million years... ;) In any case I had to remove "packageFlags" attributes from all GPOs that had applications one by one. Those GPOs are gone but gpofixup now completes the process successfully.